# Error when deleting a row from datatable in subsequent pages when using paging

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hello everybody I am using jquery datatable and am using the following function to delete rows from the table:

```
$ (document). ready (function () {
    $ (". delete.") on ("click", function () {
        var tr = $ (this) closest ('tr').;
        tr.css ("background-color", "# FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut (400, function () {
            tr.remove ();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

on the first page is all fine, but when using pagination and try to delete a row from page 2 onwards, nothing happens.

What can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On pagination click event may be unbinding. Try to bind event on document.

Comment: I do not understand how I do it?

Comment: $ (document). ready (function () {
$ (document).on("click", ".delete", function () {
        var tr = $ (this) closest ('tr').;
        tr.css ("background-color", "# FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut (400, function () {
            tr.remove ();
        });
        return false;
    });
});

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly.

Thanks again ;)